# How to make a one fragment screen always in landscape mode and reamaining not.?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity which i am using as host for calling all my  fragments.I am using `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)` for setting screen in landscape mode.But problem is that it is  making every fragment in landscape mode because their is only one parent activity for all of them.I can not use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` because this will also work the same.

I want one of my fragment to be displayed always in landscape mode and remaining fragment as according to device orientation.Is their is another ways for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna show one specific Fragment in landscape you can call

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

in the onCreate() of your Fragment.

In this Fragments onPause() f.e. you can call

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

which is the default value and enables screen rotation changes.

Comment: It does not work. Actually I have on camera fragment for capturing and on for showing preview of captured image.When I put this code in on Create method camera preview is not being launched and For other fragments its freeze the screen for sometimes.